# Using ADF, how to move files (w/ same name) in different folders on azure blob into a single folder

Tags: azure-data-factory

Move the latest modified file with same name in different folders on a blob into a single folder.

For example, blue.csv is placed as below,

Main_folder/Folder_X/Folder_A/Folder_1 has blue.csv --> Modified time Jan 1, 2023
Main_folder/Folder_X/Folder_B/Folder_2 has blue.csv --> Modified time Jan 3, 2023
Main_folder/Folder_X/Folder_C/Folder_3 has blue.csv --> Modified time Jan 5, 2023
Main_folder/Folder_X/Folder_D/Folder_4 has blue.csv --> Modified time Jan 6, 2023
Main_folder/Folder_X/Folder_E/Folder_5 has blue.csv --> Modified time Jan 7, 2023

Need to move latest modified file into Main_folder/blue.csv --> Modified time Jan 7, 2023

Comment: Main_folder/blue.csv - Is this your target file? And do you want to merge all required source files into single target file?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula<br/>
You are partly correct!<br/>

Yes, Main_folder/blue.csv is the target file.<br/>

But, I need the latest file **ONLY ** (by last modified date). In the above scenario, below file is the latest and thats the only file that I need in Main_folder.<br/>

Main_folder/Folder_X/Folder_E/Folder_5 has blue.csv --> Modified time Jan 7, 2023

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only Using Copy activity, it might not be possible to achieve your requierement.

In ADF only Get Meta data activity will get the last modified date of a file. But your folder structure is complex, so you need to first get the list of all required file paths in the main folder.

I have used dataflow for that. I took same folder structure like yours. Create a csv dataset and give your source container name in it like below.

[image]

Create a dataflow and give the above dataset as source to the dataflow and give the below wild card path.

```
Main_folder/Folder_X/*/*/blue.csv
```

And give a column name for the file path. We are going to use this column for the list of file paths.

[image]

This will merge all the required files data and adds a column for the file path and stored the respective file path in it.

[image]

Then, use the **aggregate transformation** and use the `filepath` column for the **group by** and take any sample column(like count) for the **aggregate**. This will give the file path column and another sample column with count of particular file path.

We only want the `filepath` column, so Use **select transformation**, **Rule based transformation** to filter the required column.

Then give the sink and use the **sink cache** and select the **Write to activity output** in it. This will write the `filepath` column as Dataflow activity output(JSON array).

Now in the pipeline, take the dataflow activity and give our dataflow and give the below settings.

[image]

Give the dataflow activity output array to the ForEach activity.

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value
```

[image]

Create two variables `date` and `path` in the pipeline. Give the old date for the date. We are going to use this variable in a loop and compare with every files modified date and if its greater, update the `date` with **current file modified date** and `path` with current file path.

[image]

Create another csv dataset with a dataset parameter for the file path.

[image]

Inside the ForEach, take the Get Meta data activity and give the current file path and last modified date.

[image]

Check the date in the if activity with below expression.

```
@greaterOrEquals(ticks(activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified), ticks(variables('date')))
```

In True activities of if, update the `date` with `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified` and `path` with `@item().filepath` using set variable activities.

At the end of the ForEach activity, the latest file path will be stored in `path` variable and use this in the copy activity source file name after ForEach.

[image]

In the sink, give your target file path and execute the pipeline.

**Result:**

[image]

**My Dataflow JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "source_csvs",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "aggregate1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          Id as short,",
                "          Name as string,",
                "          Age as short,",
                "          marks as short",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     rowUrlColumn: 'filepath',",
                "     wildcardPaths:['Main_folder/Folder_X/*/*/blue.csv']) ~> source1",
                "source1 aggregate(groupBy(filepath),",
                "     count = count(filepath)) ~> aggregate1",
                "aggregate1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          each(match(name=='filepath'))",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**My Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "Pipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Data flow1",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "dataflow1",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference"
                    },
                    "compute": {
                        "coreCount": 8,
                        "computeType": "General"
                    },
                    "traceLevel": "None",
                    "cacheSinks": {
                        "firstRowOnly": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Data flow1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata1",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "files_csv",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@item().filepath",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "lastModified"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "@greaterOrEquals(ticks(activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified), ticks(variables('date')))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Update the current path",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "Update the date",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "path",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@item().filepath",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Update the date",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "date",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "typeConversion": true,
                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "files_csv",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "filename": {
                                "value": "@variables('path')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "files_csv",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "filename": "Main_folder/blue.csv"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "date": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "2022-10-20"
            },
            "path": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```